# Problem with autocommit in ANT SQL task

Tags: sql, ant, task, autocommit

I have an SQL script and want to apply it witn ANT task.
This script clears out schema, creates new tables and views.

The ANT defined task as follows:

```
<sql driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://host:3306/smth"
        userid="smth"
        password="smth"
        expandProperties="false"
        autocommit="true"             
        src="all.sql"
         >
</sql>
```

When this task launches, it shows in log that tables are cleared and created. But when it tries to create first view, it fails with:

```
Failed to execute:  CREATE VIEW component... AS SELECT component_raw.id AS
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'component_raw' doesn't exist
```

I have no idea why it fails here.
Running this all.sql from MySQL query browser gives no errors.
When I launched ANT with -v option, I didn't see any "COMMIT" messages..

Please, help to resolve the problem.

Comment: CREATE VIEW is a DDL (Data Definition Language) statement, not a SQL one. You don't need COMMIT for DDLs. Are you sure the `component_raw` exists?

Comment: In all.sql I have:
DROP TABLE component_raw;
..
CREATE TABLE component_raw(..);
..
CREATE VIEW component .. // based on component_raw

The table component_raw should be created, but as there is no COMMIT relative to its creation, at the time when create view executes, it is not exists yet in DB..

Maybe I should create views just by runninng exec task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely the same issue, it turned out that I had comments in my sql files started with **#**. 
After replacing **#** for **-- ** everything works fine.

Comment: That's exactly what helped for me! Comments style